# How do you display data from a (mongo) database on to a web page html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am able to connect to my database and see the data in an array using below code

```
   app.get('/goalkeepers', (req, res) => {

     Transfer.find({}, (err, found)=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
      }

    else {
     res.json(found)
```

with Transfer being the schema model to connect to collection in database.
When i load the html page i can see array of all saved data from db so thats cool, i know i can access it and its there and working.

But how can i show this data on an actual html page in nice format etc, not just the raw data.

of course I would render a specific page eg. res.render(**pagename**) where currently you can see res.json(found)

I googled a lot and mostly confusing as a newbie, surely can be a simple way to get this data on to my web pages?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file with ext EJS and send your data to it. You can use CSS to style your data.

Watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5eCYKiZN-4

Comment: thanks i use hbs so hopefully similar, i know about that i just dont know how to send the data from database to the file

Comment: @crackahack Yes, it is the same.